# Creating Hilbert Matrix with Dynamic Size and Position Using HTML, CSS, and PHP

Tags: php, html, css

My task is as follows:
Create with HTML, CSS and PHP the Hilbert matrix for any n >= 1, n should be defined as a variable in the PHP source code for this purpose. In addition, the matrix brackets are to be displayed.

Hint: The form "TV-Screen" from https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/ could be used as a template. Use PHP to dynamically calculate the size and position of the brackets depending on the selected n.

I now have the following code that does this for n = 4.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
}

td {
  padding: 10px; 
  color: black;
}

.tv-screen {
  position: relative;
  width: 230px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 20px;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 60% / 30%;
  color: white;
  text-indent: .1em;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.tv-screen::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 8%;
  bottom: 8%;
  right: -1%;
  left: -1%;
  background: black;
  border-radius: 15% / 20%;
  z-index: -1; 
}

.matrix-entry {
  color: black;
  position: relative; 
  z-index: 1; 
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$n = 4; 

echo "<div class='tv-screen'>";
echo "<table>";
for ($i = 1; $i <= $n; $i++) {
  echo "<tr>";
  for ($j = 1; $j <= $n; $j++) {
    $value = round(1 / ($i + $j - 1), 3);
    echo "<td class='matrix-entry'>" . $value . "</td>";
  }
  echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
echo "</div>";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Furthermore I tried which values I need for width and height for n=8, n=10 and n=16.
For n=8 this is about 480px and 420px, for n=10 600px and 520px and for n=16 about 970px and 870px.

But now I have problems to dynamically adjust the position and size as required. Could someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see your heights and widths are estimates.

It looks like width is around (n x 60) px and height is (n x 53) px.

To separate the CSS/PHP, get rid of the width/height in your css for **.tv-screen**.

And in php you can change the beginning like this. Where you declare N, the Width and height. Then add them to a custom style on the div. You can also change the 60/53 multipliers as needed.

```
$n = 8; 
$width = $n * 60;
$height = $n * 53;
echo "<div style='height:{$height}px;width:{$width}px;' class='tv-screen'>";
```

Or you can use CSS calc and declare $n at the top of the page. Then in your CSS for tv-screen:

```
width: calc(<?php echo $n?> * 60px);
height: calc(<?php echo $n?> * 53px);
```